# Setting publishing file path in flash with actionscript?

Tags: actionscript-3, file, flash, output

Is there any way to use such as a constant in AS3, to define the publishing output file in flash pro in the code?

Reason being, having a different output file for different pages makes it tedious to go to file > publish settings, and then enter the path manually each time. Since the output files have similar names, if possible in actionscript, I'd only need to change a character or two without going to file etc first. Is there any way?

Comment: Might be something you could write as a JSLF extension.  http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-new-features-for-flash-with-jsfl--active-3791   AND https://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fhelp.adobe.com%2Fen_US%2Fflash%2Fcs%2Fextend%2Fflash_cs5_extending.pdf&ei=cgKuU6TYE5DaoASX6IGwBg&usg=AFQjCNHSRUtg54hM5TlKmDbqNiuFwU_S_A&sig2=LnUGbBkmKVnqzMEmlbUcsw

Comment: I just think it might not be good for me, since I'm using one and the same flash file which I keep publishing with slight modifications and names. Will JSLF be able to automate that?

Comment: yes you should be able to do that in JSFL. I do use JSFL quite a lot but for duplicating swf output I prefer a quick AIR app to do the job which anyone can do in about 10 minutes using FB 4.7 (using components) and mostly File and FileReference classes. Each time the swf output is updated (published) that little app copy that swf to all paths I specified. Like I said quite simple AIR app to put together in no time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible using actionscript, but you could try writing a jsfl script to publish, which lets you set a file path. You can also write a script to handle the publishing of multiple flas instead of opening and manually publishing each one.

[Adobe Flash Professional  document.exportSWF()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flash/cs/extend/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9024f3f-7e10CS5.html)